# Give ag-grid-angular last page information with server side pagination

Tags: angular, ag-grid, server-side-rendering, server-side, ag-grid-angular

I use ag-grid entreprise in my angular application. I have a server-side pagination.
My response from the server return my data and :

```
"page": 1,
"page_size": 10,
"total_page": 7
```

I don't know how I can use total_page so my grid can render : 'Page 1 of 7' instead of 'Page 1 of more'.
This is better for the end user and avoid error because ag-grid tries to reach the next page while it does not exists. How can I use this information ?

This is params.success from the getRow() method :

```
 params.success({
    rowData: data,
    rowCount: this.getRowCount(
       data,
       params.api.paginationGetPageSize(),
       params.api.paginationGetCurrentPage(),
     ),
  );

    private getRowCount(data, pageSize: number, currentPage: number): number | undefined {
    console.log(currentPage);
    if (!data.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    return data.length < pageSize ? pageSize * currentPage + data.length : undefined;
}
```

Comment: could you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated, if you could give some dummy data of how the pagination response will look like, this issue can be taken to closure!

Comment: @NarenMurali unfortunately, I can not share a replicated project. Do you need specific code?
More than showing the total_page number, I am looking for a way to make ag-grid understand when the last page is reached and that it should deactivate the "next" button. Actually, if pageSize === data.length, my understanding is that ag-grid think there is more data to call, even if currentPage is last page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `rowCount` can you try supplying `lastRow` as a number, the same can be calculated as shown below!

Please refer to the below plunkr and try to supply data as shown in that example, it might solve your issue!

```
 params.success({
    rowData: data.rows,
    lastRow: data.total_page * data.page_size,
  );
```

[Aggrid SSR Pagination Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&preview)

[Ag grid docs - Example: Server-Side Pagination](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/server-side-model-pagination/#example-server-side-pagination)

Comment: I tried this but lastRow is not recognized. I have an error :
Object literal may only specify known properties, and  lastRow  does not exist in type LoadSuccessParams. I use version version 28.1.1

Comment: @Ryley38 Its from the official documentation, please check your imports or just give any data type instead!